# How can I draw image from USB digital camera(RAW)?

Tags: android

I connected USB digital camera to my android tablet. I have got data from camera. This data is representing RAW byte array. And my questions is following:

1. Is there any libraries to convert RAW to RGB (demosaic)?

2. How to draw a byte array to View? or how to create bitmap from byte[], where 1 pixel - 1 byte ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/

Comment: And my another question - how to fast transfrorm array of byte[] to array colors ?